# 'Convert' ascii String to positive numbers only

Tags: php

What's the most space efficient algorithm or way to convert a 20 character ascii string to numbers only?

**example:**
This is what i have done: `'ADF' = '65 68 70'`

I need something like this: `'ADF' = '8758755' <= using as few numbers as possible`

Comment: Do you mean converting it to an array of ascii values?

Comment: I think he/she means a string to each character's decimal (mind reading) ascii value?

Comment: @user3054967 you should really include an example of what you want when you ask a question like this by the way

Comment: @Emissary: correct, you can try to became a medium.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$input = "abcdefg";
$split = str_split($input);
$result = "";
foreach ($split as $item) {
    $result .= ord($item);
}
echo $result;
```

`abcdefg` = `979899100101102103` aka `97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103`

Comment: Thanks for you effort, no. I am looking for a compression method.

Comment: @user3054967 why not just use an existing compression method like [gzdeflate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php)?

Comment: I need to convert a 20 character string to a 40 character int in order to be stored in a database as int. I am asking, if there is a way to convert the 20 string characters to something less than 40 int.

Comment: @user3054967 I don't see a way to shrink the amount of size it will take when storing it as a plain 40 digit number. Even if you can get it smaller, I would think that the amount of effort required would outweigh the few bits you can save. Is there a reason you want it shorter than 40 and not 40?

Comment: Well, does it really make a difference if the primary key is int or char on a 500m row database?

Comment: @user3054967 Well limiting to a certain number of decimal digits as an integer makes it a bit hard to compress I would think. If you want to fully represent any character in the ascii table (255) then you use 8 bits or 1 byte. A standard int value is 32 bits with a max value of 4294967295 or 10 digits. Thats only 4 characters you can represent with 10 digits.